# Using one repository with Ranorex for all my tests

Tags: ranorex

My understanding is that for items in the repository you can give then logical names. Therefore instead of typing them in for each test, is it possible to have one repository for all your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to use a single repository for all of your tests. Simply specify a different base xpath for each item. eg

> Base: /contextmenu[@processname='iexplore']
>
> Base: /dom[@domain='google.com']

It may then be useful to store the repository in it's own solution and then link your test solutions to the repository in the repo solution.

In our interactions with Ranorex they have suggested splitting them up because of the size of them. We have also had a fair amount of difficulty merging different versions of the repo in version control which has been a reason for us to split them up as much as possible.